# When and where is the Meteor.settings object initialized?

Tags: javascript, meteor

As title says, i need to know when the `Meteor.settings` object is initialized.

What i want to do is, create this object in advance with some default values and overwrite any of these values with the values from the settings file when the object is initialized by meteor.

Atm i apply default values like this:

settings.json:

```
{
    "foo" : {
        "bar":true
    }
}
```

javascript:

```
bar = Meteor.settings.foo.bar == undefined ? false : Meteor.settings.foo.bar;
```

Which i will have to do for every property...

And it would be much nicer just to create the `Meteor.settings.foo` object in advance and overwrite the properties when they are present in the settings file.

Update:
Ok i found the problem....

I was setting the foo.bar right outside a function:

```
var foo = Meteor.settings.foo
```

So it was not defined at this point. But later in the function when i accesed the property i did not get the updated reference to Meteor.settings.foo;

Anyways thx for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Meteor.settings` will be loaded right from the moment server started. However, you can override that object any times you want. 
I normally put the overriding in the server/main.js, inside `Meteor.startup`.

```
// server/main.js

Meteor.startup(() => {
  Meteor.settings = {} // your new object

})
```

However, be careful about the overriding. Throughout the system, it should be done one time and in one place so everything is consistent.

Comment: Hello, i added a property `Meteor.settings.foo` which i directly out printed. But it seems when i try to acces this property after the `Meteor server restarted` or `Started your app` then the property foo is undefined.

Comment: where do you access the `foo` property ? you cannot put freely the properties inside the `Meteor.settings`. Read more about settings here https://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-settings

Comment: created a file `/server/defaults.js` and put the code inside like this `if(Meteor.isServer){ Meteor.startup( function () { Meteor.settings.foo = {..} console.log(Meteor.settings)} });`

Answer (score 1):

To get a dictionnary of all your settings in Meteor, i suggest you to use this little code in your Meteor.startup function :

```
Meteor.startup(function() {

    // read environment variables from Meteor.settings
    if(Meteor.settings && _.isObject(Meteor.settings)) {
        for(let variableName in Meteor.settings) {
            process.env[variableName] = Meteor.settings[variableName];
        }
    }
});
```

You can now access to your settings as this in your server-side :

```
process.env.foo.bar
```

Hope it will help.